# drawing rainbow palettes

Tags: c++, color-palette

I have a 8-bit color palette, therefore I am having 256 colors.

The palette is basically an array of [256 * 3] `{r, g, b}` values, Now I need to draw a color spectrum out of it. So basically I have to select 256 out of total `256*256*256` values possible which would enable me to draw the rainbow as closely as possible.

Similar questions here on SO point to HSV based approach, but I am looking for an RGB implementation coz I have APIs defined that way.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: HSV is the way to go and convert to RGB for each HSV value you have.

Comment: Actually, HSL might work as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The HSV solution is still correct, because that pretty much captures your problem. A "rainbow" is by definition a series of colors with constant S and V, but varying H.

Comment: Yup use the right color model which does what you want, and then convert.

Comment: can you elaborate how I can vary the hue from 0-360 to generate 256 colors

Comment: "Hue" is not necessarily an integer. Store it in a `double`, and increment it in steps of (360.0/256.0). You'll of course end up with `double` values of R,G and B. Round them when you put the color in the palette, not earlier.

Answer (score 1):

It really is easiest to use HSV, because that's what you'll end up implementing anyway. Keep S and V fixed (both at 1) and let H vary from 0° to 360°.

The recipe for converting HSV to RGB is described on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#From_HSV).

Comment: vary from 0 to 360? I just have 256 colors?

Comment: Hue is often measured in degrees, on the colour wheel. You can use 0..255, or 0..1, or 0%..100%, as long as you normalize the equations accordingly.